# How does FSA work in case of change in employment?

Tags: united-states, irs, fsa, dependents

I have a Dependent Care account with WageWorks from my previous company. I left my previous company in July'15. There are still $2000.00 in WageWorks account.
Now WageWorks is not letting me claim any child care services from this account. They are saying that account is valid till March'16 but I can only claim for services obtained before July'15.
What should I do now? Is this how it work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately that is exactly how FSA works. When your employment ended with that company, that puts a early end date on the funds. You can still submit bills, but only if they are for the period between January 1st 2015 and your last day under the plan.

If there are any bills from earlier in the year, you can still submit them. Otherwise there is nothing you can do.